# Angular ui-router doesn't resolve $http.get

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use ui-router's resolve feature rather than attaching a service's returned value in a controller (to $scope), but I'm stuck.

Here's my plunk
http://plnkr.co/edit/m94IqBpgbEjtuLBhQVB6?p=preview

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="restprac">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>REST!</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

image.html

```
<img ng-src="{{image}}">
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('restprac', ['ngResource', 'ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("singleImage", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: image.html,
    resolve: {
      Image: 'Image',
      imageResource: function(Image) {
        return imageResource.query().$promise;
      }
    },
    controller: 'ImageController'
  });
}]);


app.factory('Image', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('https://httpbin.org/image');
}]);

app.controller('ImageController', ['$scope', 'Image', function($scope, Image) {
  $scope.image = Image;
}]);
```

Comment: You don't have any ui-view anywhere. So you're effectively not using ui-router.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems:

- you don't define the `templateUrl` of the state;
- the `imageResource` attribute of resolve is useless, not used anywhere, and uses an undefined `imageResource` variable;
- the URL `https://httpbin.org/image` points to an actual image, and you're trying to use that image as the `src` attribute of an `img` tag, which expects a URL, not an image;
- you forget to get the data out of the HTTP response.
- you don't navigate to the state

Here's a modified plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/uCXDOBEFNyaYkuIegY0N?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('restprac', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("singleImage", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    resolve: {
      imageUrl: 'image',
    },
    controller: 'ImageController'
  });
}]);

app.run(function($location) {
  $location.path('/');
});

app.factory('image', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('imageUrl.txt').then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
}]);

app.controller('ImageController', ['$scope', 'imageUrl', function($scope, imageUrl) {
  $scope.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but more importantly, thank you for your patience.